# How do I hide selected folders in Windows home folder?

Tags: windows-8

There are some folders in the home folder that I do not wish to see, specifically the "Links", "Favorites", and "Contacts" folders. Is there a way to hide them from sight (tried making them hidden, didn't work)?

I'm using Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not folders, the are [Libraries](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/libraries-faq). Because they are links to other locations and not the location themselves you can just simply delete the ones you do not want, it will not harm the files they point to (but it may make it harder to find them in the future).

Comment: Doesn't work. Deleting the folder only results in the emptying of the real location off all files, and the library folder remains in the home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete them.
They are just folders and can be deleted like any others.

I never use the contacts or favourites folders so I just deleted them, and they've stayed gone.
If you start up Internet Explorer, favourites will probably come back. I'm not sure if there's anything that will do the same for Contacts or Links, but i haven't seen them come back since I removed them.